# Using one PHP master page with JQuery controls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I currently have a small project which uses PHP pages on Apache, hosted on a Raspberry Pi. However, I feel that using AJAX to send JSON to different PHP pages, then having those pages do something in response is just messy.

I have so many files, remembering all my variable names, functions, and file names just causes a headache.

Why is this the preferred way to code PHP?

I would rather just create one PHP page which has multiple classes/functions. Then use JQuery to Load() static HTML 'forms'. So a web interaction would look like this...

```
<?php 
//some server-side functions
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
//some Jquery to load your seperate html forms
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="html forms get loaded into here">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am very new to PHP and very partial to ASP/.NET. Obviously this is terrible if you want to create large sites accessed by lots of people... but for a small project, is this still a bad idea?

Comment: `"I have so many files, remembering all my variable names, functions, and file names just causes a headache."` - It sounds like the problem here is that you're trying to keep *your entire application* in your head all at once.  You should organize your code into smaller components, and each individual component should make sense in a smaller scope.  Keep in mind the saying, "Complex things are made of many simple things."  You're indicating that you are having trouble keeping one complex thing in your head. Instead, compose it of many simple things and just keep a subset of those in your head.

Comment: Look into a good MVC framework, like [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), especially the latter has very good screencasts to get you started. Btw, +1 for the Raspberry Pi hosting :-)

Comment: @David While I agree that it is best to stay as organized as possible, and a part of that is breaking down large components into a set of smaller ones is beneficial in doing so... Why would I want to break my code into so many different files? If I have maybe 10 functions, I really shouldn't need 5-6 files. Not to mention the headache of trying to keep it all in-session across multiple pages.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the feedback! I really wanted to use django, but for my first Pi project I choose the simplest.. appache and mysql play nice together and I've already used those before. But for the next project, you can be your bottom dollar I use it ;)

Comment: @Christopher: If the code is simple enough that a single file can reasonably and clearly contain it, then a single file is fine.  As the complexity of the project increases, so does the need for disparity of the individual components.  Especially if any of those components can be re-used by other projects.  There is no single rule by which one must separate one's components, it's entirely based on the needs and constraints of that particular codebase.

Comment: [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) might be worth a try as well.